# How to pass QLineEdit text to MS Access DB?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access, qt4, pyqt4

I am using the INSERT query, which works fine if I pass a string in the VALUES, like below:

```
oConn.Execute("Insert into Student_Info(Student_Name) values ('Robin')")
```

But I am getting an error if I pass the QLineEdit.text() this way:

```
oConn.Execute("Insert into Student_Info(Student_Name) values ('"& (self.StudentName.text()) &"')")
```

Error:

```
oConn.Execute("Insert into Student_Info(Student_Name) values ('"& (self.StudentName.text()) &"')")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'QString'
```

Please suggest, I am not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use python pass string easy way, like this;

```
command = '''Insert into Student_Info(Student_Name) values ('%s')''' % str(self.StudentName.text())
oConn.Execute(command)
```

Or your can use string concat;

```
command = "Insert into Student_Info(Student_Name) values ('" + str(self.StudentName.text()) + "')"
oConn.Execute(command)
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please suggest what is wrong in my code?

Comment: The Ampersand (&) operator use in bit OR operator not to use string concat operator. If your want to use string concat, I recommend to use plus (+) operator.

Comment: I used this, it worked : oConn.Execute("Insert into Student_Info(Student_Name) values ('"+ (self.StudentName.text() +"')

Comment: Yes, It should be it. But in your question, your use Ampersand (&) operator. It's has error.

Comment: Sorry, The Ampersand (&) operator use in bit AND operator not OR operator.